# Catch logout action from facebook Logout button - facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Currently i am devloping a facebook authenticated android application.I have done the authentication application with facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0.
it works fine.
After login , the same button act as logout . But the problem is . i need to catch the logout action event from the facebook logout Button can you guys help me on this?

or is there any other way to implement the Logout functionality.
please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [LoginManager.logOut()](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/login/LoginManager.java#L236) to log out the user. You can use the AccessTokenTracker to detect when the access token goes null, here's [an example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/b384c0655fe96db71229bfdcb981a522f3f1e675/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious/MainActivity.java#L62).